# What are historical examples of globalization in action?

Tags: united-states, international-relations

What specific things in society demonstrate globalization to the fullest extent?

For example, every country in the world has electricity. Would this be a successful candidate for the representation of globalization in our world?

Comment: To be honest (from the close votes), I think this would be more suited to economics.se.  However, were you to reframe the question into a historical setting, the question would be ontopic.

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:united-states]?

Answer (score 7):

Globalization as a concept includes the notion of interchange of ideas, and in that respect the obvious concrete examples come from the world of global telecommunications, telegraphy would be an early example, the internet a current one.

That said, every global (or near global) infrastructure you can think of could be considered a concrete example of globalization.

Comment: The 1901 world map that is part of the Wikipedia article on the [Victorian internet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Victorian_Internet) is also instructive.

Answer (score 6):

Anything that corresponds to *the process by which businesses or other organizations develop international influence or start operating on an international scale*. See [the Oxford dictionary definition](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/globalization).

Answer (score 4):

From a geopolitical standpoint I would say that the [United Nations](http://www.un.org/en/aboutun/history/), the [Bretton Woods Institutions](http://www.brettonwoodsproject.org/item.shtml?x=320747) ([World Bank](http://web.worldbank.org/WBSITE/EXTERNAL/EXTABOUTUS/EXTARCHIVES/0,,contentMDK:20053333~menuPK:63762~pagePK:36726~piPK:36092~theSitePK:29506,00.html) and [International Monetary Fund](http://www.imf.org/external/about/history.htm)), and the [World Trade Organization](http://www.wto.org/english/thewto_e/whatis_e/inbrief_e/inbr01_e.htm) are the clearest examples of globalization.

These organizations are the vehicles through which the countries of the world interact with each other, exchange ideas, handle problems created by new technologies, trade with each other, etc.

Globalization really began with the [rise of international trade](http://www.econlib.org/library/Columns/Irwintrade.html), because trade is one of the chief ways that countries exchange ideas, and is also one of the motivating factors behind the actions of states.

All of the organizations (UN, WB, IMF, WTO) deal in some ways with the free flow of trade, ideas, and people, which is what globalization is largely about.